# UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView with a View inside of it.  Inside of that view is a bunch of buttons, labels, etc that fit in the View when in Portrait mode...When the iPad is rotated, I want the scrollView to kick in so the user can scroll to the bottom of the view.  The app runs, but when I rotate it, the scroller never works...I believe I've wired everything up correctly and I have this code in the viewDidLoad event:

```
[scrollview addSubview: masterView]; 
scrollView.contentSize = [masterView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
```

Is there something else I am missing?  Do I need to modify the size when the iPad rotates?

thanks

Comment: You don't need to modify the size after rotating if you set the view's [autoresizingMask](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) properly.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with the content size of the `UIScrollView`. Without the contentSize being set larger than the actual scrollView size, scroll bars won't be shown.

You can code this in with something like this:

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(2000,2000)];
```

And then changing the content size to the actual content size of what you are putting in the `UIScrollView` (`scrollView`).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the results of `[masterView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero]` (e.g. NSLog or set a breakpoint in your debugger, I think you will find that it's not what you expected it to be. You might find that masterView has autoResize parameters set (which is common for a view that covers the entire screen), which means that it might, itself, be getting resized too short to fit all of its controls and scrollView is simply grabbing this shortened value itself. Take a look at that CGSize and the problem will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation but my case was iPhone.

Remember that content should be larger than scroll for scrollView to kick in.

"Why would you want to go down if everything is visible in front of you ?"

use the following code:

```
  [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(intValue, intValue)];
```

intValue: Integer values setting width and height of scroll.

Even if it doesn't works, don't worry there are loads of other options to figure out the solution:
1. NSLog 
2. Breakpoints
3. Put up errors you are getting from console on stackoverflow